# PHP Session Not Being Created...WHY?

Tags: php, session

So this is driving me crazy, I can authenticate fine, and get the desired authentication variable to store in the session, but it's not being stored, I've checked PHPInfo and the Godaddy server does have sessions enabled...what the heck am I doing wrong?

```php
<?php
session_start();

require 'Soundcloud.php';

$soundcloud = new Services_Soundcloud('XXX','XXX','XXX');

$authURL = $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();

echo "<pre>";
echo "<a href='$authURL'>Connect To Soundcloud</a>";

try {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $access_Token['access_token'];
    }
    else {
        $soundcloud->setAcessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
```

Comment: It is not stored because `$access_Token` does **not** exist. Replace that line by this one: `$_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['access_token'];`

Comment: Try adding this at the end of your file and see what it spits out: `print '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION); print '</pre>';` Where exactly are you having your issue? Can you elaborate?

Comment: thanks for the replies guys, I've tried both of those already with no luck, it's not printing anything for the session which is ultimately my problem.

Comment: Justin , you're incorrect, I can print the values of access token, so access token does exist, if I remove or replace the line I can no longer authenticate.  Any more suggestions?